# Simplifying $\theta u^2 + (1-\theta)v^2 - [\theta u + (1-\theta)v]^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working through a problem in Chiang's Fundamental Methods of Mathematical Economics and I ran into a little bit of trouble. So the problem is to check whether a function is concave or convex and you're supposed to use a formula that is provided. The problem you end up with after plugging into the formula is $\theta u^2 + (1-\theta)v^2 - [\theta u + (1-\theta)v]^2$ and you need to simplify it to be able to determine whether it is greater than or equal to, or less than or equal to zero. $0<\theta<1$. I end up with $\theta (1-\theta)(u-v)^2$ but Chiang end ups with $(1-\theta)(u-v)^2$ and I don't seem to understand how he does that.

Comment: Putting in $\theta = 1/2$ and $(u,v) = (1,0)$ it shows you were right and it could be a typo.

Comment: $\theta=0$ is a root, you are right. Also the formula is invariant to a substitution $\theta\leftrightarrow 1-\theta,u\leftrightarrow v$.

Comment: Your result is perfectly correct. Probably, one more typo in a book !

Comment: Thank you all, it's starting to look more and more like a typo in the book.